# USA ESTA and j-1 visa application

Tags: canada, us-visa-waiver-program, study

I am Japanese.
I was accepted to do internship at university in USA.
This university is very close to Canada.
I wonder if it is possible that I enter US by ESTA and travel somewhere and then receive DS-2019 face to face, and go to US consulate in Canada to get Visa. 
Is it ilegal?

I tried to find out about this but I could not get information that I ex
actly need.
Please give me your knowleage.

Comment: Yes you can do so. It is not illegal.

Comment: I fear this might be better on Expats rather than Travel.

Comment: on the official paper, my intern will be started on 15th July. If I stay in US by ESTA until over 15th, it would be illegal. But if I just go to Canada before 15th, the stay before 15th is regarded as travel not for intern, not for any other reasons. Isn't it? Yes I know, if they,US immigration office, regard traveling Canada as leaving US is big worrisome.